# How do change the save location of files when file names are being saved based on a list?

Tags: python, csv

How can I customize the save path for the to_csv function below? I have multiple files that are being pulled via Python and the files are being saved as with the date being substituted into the {date} below, but it's saving to where the script is located. How can I change the save location?

```
df_call.to_csv(f'call_{date}.csv')
df_put.to_csv(f'put_{date}.csv')
```

Comment: Use absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write path;

**windows**

```py
df_call.to_csv(f'C:\\Users\\YOURUSERNAME\\Desktop\\call_{date}.csv')
```

**linux**

```py
df_put.to_csv(f'~/Desktop/put_{date}.csv')
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks for this. It turns out it was not working before because I had single backslashes instead of double backslashes. Do you know why it does not work with single backslash?

Comment: In Python strings, the backslash "\" is a special character, also called the "escape" character. It is used in representing certain whitespace characters: "\t" is a tab, "\n" is a newline, and "\r" is a carriage return. Conversely, prefixing a special character with "\" turns it into an ordinary character.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) and [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) modules in the python standard library. Utilizing these modules, your operations will be more robust and work across different OS.

To save a file to a parent folder, you can do the following:

```py
from pathlib import Path
...
scriptpath = Path(__file__) # e.g. /home/usr/scripts/script.py
parentfolder = scriptpath.parents[1] # /home/usr/
outputdir = parentfolder / 'output' # /home/usr/output
filename = 'output.csv'
outputpath = outputdir / filename # /home/usr/output/output.csv
```